# Realm causing program to behave unexpectedly. (OS X and Swift)

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm

So I am creating a fairly simple program using Realm as my database.  I am fairly new to programing in Swift (or any OS X or iOS environment.)  In my program when a button is pressed `IBAction func createInvoice` I want a few things to happen, I want to count the previous rows in the database and create an invoice number, I want to write new data to the database and I want to call a new view and view controller and pass along the invoice number.  My code works except for one thing when using Realm the new view controller is called (`override func prepareForSegue`) before the invoice number is created so a 0 value is passed along to the new view controller.

If I create a dummy invoice number value such as `let invoicenumber = 42` everything works perfectly.  It seems that Realm is causing things to happen 'out of order' How can I make the veiwcontroller wait for a value before loading?

```
@IBAction func createInvoice(sender: AnyObject) {
 let realm = Realm()
let invoicepull = Invoice()
let invoicecount = realm.objects(Invoice)
let invoicenraw = invoicecount.count
let a = 100
let invoicenumber = a + invoicenraw
var invoicefile = Invoice()
invoicefile.inumber = invoicenumber
invoicefile.cnumber = clientcombo.stringValue
invoicefile.cost = owed.doubleValue
invoicefile.paid = paid.doubleValue
invoicefile.sevicecode = service.stringValue
invoicefile.dateofservice = NSDate()
// Save your object
realm.beginWrite()
realm.add(invoicefile)
realm.commitWrite()
//Sent notification
performSegueWithIdentifier("cinvoiceseuge", sender: nil)
println("Inside Action")
println(invoicenumber)
dismissViewController(self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "cinvoiceseuge") {
    //Checking identifier is crucial as there might be multiple
    // segues attached to same view
    var detailVC = segue.destinationController as! invociegenerator;
    detailVC.toPass = invoicenumber
    println("Inside Sugue")
    println(invoicenumber)
}
}
```

Comment: You need to use an asynchronous programming pattern. For example, use a notification/callback to load the contents of your presented view once the Realm operation has finished. (In the meantime you can present an activity indicator in the view)

Comment: GCD (Grand Central Dispatch, the dispatch_* methods) may be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, thanks to the help of @Shmidt by using Realm's built in notification center.  To use the notifications you can use this basic structure.

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

deinit{
let realm = Realm()
if let notificationToken = notificationToken{
    realm.removeNotification(notificationToken)
}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let realm = Realm()
notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
   println("The realm is complete")
}
...
}
```

One small other error in my code was `let invoicenumber = a + invoicenraw` I needed to drop the `let` as it is a variable and not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If `createInvoice` is happening on a different thread than `prepareForSegue`, you'll have to refresh the realm (`Realm().refresh()`) before accessing your `invoicenumber` variable (which I assume is of type `RealmSwift.Object`).